# POST an Ajax form from a Kendo UI window

Tags: kendo-ui, ajax.beginform

To edit a record, I'm opening a modal Kendo UI window populated with a partial view containing an AJAX enabled form:

```
@model MVC_ACME_Hardware.Models.BaseModel

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("form").kendoValidator();
    });
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditProduct", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ProductDiv", OnSuccess = "SomeMethod" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>EmployeeFTE</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Products.Product_ID)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Products.Product_Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Products.Product_Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Products.Product_Name)
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="myButton" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

When I run the form and click 'Save' on the popup, the form posts successfully but the post is not done via AJAX and my 'SomeMethod' onsuccess method is not being called. I've tried adding...

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

...on the partial view but it did not help. How can I get my form to submit using AJAX? I'm missing something obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this (attention to the input type):

```
<input type="button" value="Save" class="myButton" id="btnSave" />
```

and the in the $(document).ready() :

```
var validator = $(document.forms[0]).kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");    
$("#btnSave").click(function(e) {     
              if (validator.validate()) {
                    var formContent = $(document.forms[0]).serialize();
                    var url = $(document.forms[0]).action;
                    $.post(url, formContent).done(function(data) {
                          $(document.body).append("<div class='savedRecordMessage'>success</div>");
                    });
               }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add these files if you want to use unobtrusive validation of MVC and Ajax options of AJAX form.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```